# create new None object in embedded python

Tags: python, c, null, embedding

I am writing a simple C wrapper for a Python module.  What I need to do is create a new `PyObject*` that represents `None`.  I can't figure out how to do this.  Is there a simple function that will return a `PyObject*` pointing to `None`, similar to how `PyTuple_New` returns a `PyObject*` pointing to a new tuple or PyString_FromString` returns one pointing to a python string?

**Note** Is it possible that, when calling a function as below, passing a C `NULL` will work?  example:

```
//pFunc points to a function with 2 arguments
PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyString_FromString("hello"));
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, NULL); // <--- will this create a python object representing None?
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html), `None` is a singleton, and is accessible from C code as `Py_None`.

> `PyObject* Py_None` The Python `None` object, denoting lack of value.
>   This object has no methods. It needs to be treated just like any other
>   object with respect to reference counts.
>
> `Py_RETURN_NONE` Properly handle returning `Py_None` from within a C
>   function.